# How enable Google Cloud Tracing for all endpoints of Spring Boot 2.7.x application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gcp, google-cloud-trace

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.x application which is running GCP Kubernetes. Several GCP products are working properly including logging, datastore etc..

I wanted use Google Cloud Trace and followed this and used [GCP sample project here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/3a63b07049221ac4af62a0fe5ed5f7711a099c97/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-trace-sample)
Please note that the most recent version of this sample project uses Spring Boot 3.x.x. The provided link here is an old version which is using Spring Boot 2.7.x

**What I changed**

Application.yaml

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
    web:
      enabled: true
    enabled: true
    reactor:
      enabled: true
    async:
      enabled: true
      client:
        template:
          enabled: true
  zipkin: # All zipkin features disabled for integration tests
    enabled: true
logging.level:
    org.springframework.cloud: DEBUG
    com.google.cloud: DEBUG
```

build.gradle file

```
   implementation platform("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:3.4.3")
   implementation "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-logging"
   implementation "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub"
   implementation "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace"
```

To test it, I triggered some endpoints inside my app.
In the logs there are below 2 debug logs from spring (with different ids)

```
Handled send of span [NoopSpan(656731a1275935f02630b37e25545eca/2630b37e25545eca)]
Created a server receive span [NoopSpan(656731a1e8bdc89e38f060196094f310/38f060196094f310)]
```

Even if I do not trigger any endpoint, this lines are printed in logs in regular intervals.

However no trace data arrives to Cloud Trace page. I also checked Cloud Trace API monitoring charts, again nothing arrives there.

Then I included this additional header in my endpoint request `'X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 205445aa7843bc8bf206b12000100003/1;o=1'` and it worked

And this time there were different logs; `RealSpan(205445aa7843bc8bf206b12000100002/4a30d753bbadebd2)]` before my execution and `Handled send of span [RealSpan(205445aa7843bc8bf206b12000100002/4a30d753bbadebd2)]` after the execution.

When I run it locally, it just works without X-Cloud-Trace-Context header. I see 'RealSpan(....' logs locally.

So, I think tracing is there but not activated in GCP.
According to their documentation, spring.sleuth.enabled should be automatically true thanks to "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace"
I even set it to true manually but still it only works with **X-Cloud-Trace-Context** header.  Interestingly it behaves differently on local and GCP

**What should I do to make it active for all endpoints without requiring additional header?**